# WiFi security against spoofing attacks

Tags: wifi, spoofing, raspberry-pi

I am about to install some custom pi cameras that connect to my network via WiFi. I know people hack wifi through spoofing SSID.

My password is randomly generated and is impossible to brute force even without router protection and a supercomputer. Spoofing, on the other hand, could reveal my password. Auto-connect is disabled.

How can I protect my wifi network? Should I use some certificate? Replace my router with a specific secure model?

Comment: Hello, you've got a lot of different questions going on here. It would help to clarify your exact concerns and make the question more concise.

Comment: random password doesn't mean impossible to brute force. it largely depends on what wifi connection protocol you use, e.g., WEP, WPA1, WPA2, etc. spoof ssid or hide ssid is just an initial step

Comment: @LiDong Hiding the SSID doesn't give any security benefit.

Comment: by spoofing SSID what exactly do you mean? I'm not sure in which way attackers can obtain your password without attacking client stations. As per the comment above, please state your questions more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really secure, you can just go with WPA-EAP-TLS RFC5216. You do need a RADIUS server for this, but it's one of the most secure solutions out there. It basically allows you to operate without a password, once you have the certificate setup on your device.

Comment: i do have a server in house that i use for various tasks. Thanks. So as long as the keys are safe everything is 100% secure?

Comment: and the certificate ofc. I will also set mac spoofing on any network change just in case someone probes my cams for mac addresses.